# duplicate key value violates unique constraint "core_user_username_key" DETAIL: Key (username)=() already exists

Tags: python, django

good day!A separate page was created to change the password, when you enter the password and repeat it and click on the "change password" button, a duplicate key value violates unique constraint "core_user_username_key" error appears
DETAIL: key (username) = already exists
how to solve this error?

forms.py

```
class CallcenterPasswordChange(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),  label='Новый пароль')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label='Повтор нового пароля')

    def clean(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='Повтор нового пароля не совпадает',
            )
        return self.cleaned_data

  class Meta:
     model = User
     fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1',   'password2')
```

views.py

```
class CallcenterPasswordChangeView(AbsCallcenterView):
    template_name = 'callcenter/password_change.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        patient_pk = kwargs.get('patient_pk')
        patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=patient_pk)
        initial_data = model_to_dict(patient.user)
        context['form'] =CallcenterPasswordChange(initial=initial_data)
        context['patient_pk'] = patient_pk
        context['patient'] = patient
        return context

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        patient_pk = kwargs.get('patient_pk')
        patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=patient_pk)
        form = CallcenterPasswordChange(request.POST)
        context['form_user'] = form
        context['patient'] = patient
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            return render(request, template_name=self.template_name, context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you want to do at all. What this is trying to do is to create a completely new user.

What's more, the `password1` and `password2` fields are not associated with the actual password field in the model; plus, there is nothing that takes care of hashing the password.

What you actually want is a standard (non-model) form with just those two fields, and then to set the password of the current user.

So the form is just:

```
class CallcenterPasswordChange(forms.Form):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),  label='Новый пароль')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label='Повтор нового пароля')

    def clean(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='Повтор нового пароля не совпадает',
            )
        return self.cleaned_data
```

and in the view, you do:

```
form = CallcenterPasswordChange(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    request.user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
    request.user.save()
    return redirect('somewhere')
```

However, you should also note that Django includes a password change form and view already.

Comment: according to the method proposed by you, everything works, but not in the way you would like, the password should be changed for the patient by (patient_pk) and not the user

Comment: Well, you should have said that originally. But what is the relationship between Patient and User? Show the models.

Comment: the user creates a patient, enters all his data, first name, last name, date of birth, etc., can edit his login, last name, first name, etc., as well as change his password now, so I can’t get the user to change  patient password,user has full control over the patient

Comment: What is the *code* relationship? Again, please show your models.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved!

```
 class CallcenterPasswordChangeView(AbsCallcenterView):
    template_name = 'callcenter/password_change.html'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
     patient_pk = kwargs.get('patient_pk')
     patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=patient_pk)
     initial_data = model_to_dict(patient.user)
     context['form'] = CallcenterPasswordChange(initial=initial_data)
     context['patient'] = patient
     return context

 def post(self, request, **kwargs):
     context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
     patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=context['patient_pk'])
     form = CallcenterPasswordChange(request.POST)
     context['form'] = form
     if form.is_valid():
         patient.user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
         patient.user.save()
         success_url = reverse_lazy('callcenter:patients')
         return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```